# Comparación de fecha en java

Tags: java

Buenas tengo que crear un código el cual introduzca 3 fechas  y me las compare entre si, diciendo cual es mayor que la otra

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola , cuéntanos que has intentado , que tipo de dato son tus fechas , hay muchas formas de comparar "Fechas" .

Answer (score 2):

Lo interesante es que te hagas un código que ordene n-fechas, no sólo 3. Hay decenas diferentes de hacer esta ordenación, un sencillita de entender es esta:

http://java-buddy.blogspot.com.es/2013/01/sort-list-of-date.html

Si la pasas a Java 8 con lambdas, streams...seguro que ahorras unas cuantas líneas de código. También tienes la posibilidad de recurrir a librerías de terceros como Joda http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ que te facilitan ciertas operaciones sobre fechas, aunque hoy en día las clases del JDK han mejorado mucho en su manejo de fechas respecto a versiones < 1.5.

Comment: interesante sugerencia la de Lambda (+1) pero dudo que llegue a tener esos conocimientos. la idea de meterlos en una lista está guay  ^^